# Error: Cloud function needs to be called with an event parameter. Firebase console error,

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've upgraded firebase node version from 6 to 8 also firebase-functions, typescript version as well as firebase-admin upgraded. 
But I'm getting this error on few triggers.

> Error: Cloud function needs to be called with an event parameter.If >you are writing unit tests, please use the Node module firebase-?>functions-fake.
>      at Object. (/srv/node_modules/firebase->functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:84:19)

```
exports.userFollowingChanged = functions.firestore
  .document("Db1/{domainName}/Users/{byUser}/toIds/{toId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    return wasTriggered(context.eventId, 'userFollowingChanged').then(() => {
      return userFollowingChanged(change, context)
    });
  });
```

my package.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc --skipLibCheck",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/database": "0.1.9",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "elasticsearch": "^15.1.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.13.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "stripe": "^5.5.0",
    "twilio": "^3.12.0",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
}
```

Can some one explain me what wrong with this trigger?
It was working well in node :6
I saw the same questions in stack overflow, regarding version issues.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that error?  What are you doing to trigger it?  Please walk us through what you're doing.

Comment: Did you find a solution, I have the same issue for all my functions using onWrite or onCreate after upgrading from node 6 to 8 ?

Comment: It's working after upgrading firebase-functions to 3.3.0 for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade firebase-functions       .